# Anybody do it up for Halloween?

Tags: sound-design, halloween, horror

Every year I think to myself that this'll be the year that I get it together to really scare some kids (and parents) with sound as they try and bleed me dry of my candy money, and then it doesn't happen. Too busy, too full of excuses, too whatever.

Maybe it's because I turned out to be a soundie, but it's the houses that would play those atrocious Halloween sound effects cds in quasi darkness and sit in their lawn as a scarecrow that I remember the most. Anybody go to the extreme to put on a truly haunting experience for the kids and make their own Halloween soundtrack?

I need some inspiration/challenge for the coming years! Vids and soundtracks appreciated. Happy Halloween!

Answer (score 3):

Cheat:

http://www.moogmusic.com/content/animoog

Comment: Awesome indeed! I bought the app last week even though the only ipad I have is across the country right now. Didn't know about the presets though. Downloaded! Thanks @arX!

Answer (score 0):

This Halloween was a blast - I got to create a bunch of Halloween sound assets for Rivet Games, for my current game "Pet Tales"  (free, on the Facebook platform).

Tons of fun stuff:  Original music, long  environmental ambiance loops for a "haunted cemetary", plus I got to create a few new Halloween characters as well, one of which was the voice of a giant demonic pumpkin in a Pumpkin patch maze.  Plus carniverous plants, in an "Enchanted Mushroom forest"...owls.... lots of bats!  Total blast!

bentleyaudio@sonic.net